# @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model find parameterize

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, razor

Trying to find a list in a model by an identifier in this case `taskId`

Can `taskId` be parameterized ?

---

```
function buildGrid(taskId) {

var grid = jQuery("#myGrid");

grid.jqGrid({
  //data: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Tasks.Find(z => z.TaskId == (3051)).TaskConstraints  )), // works
  data: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Tasks.Find(z => z.TaskId == (taskId)).TaskConstraints  )), // does not work
  datatype: 'local',
```

Comment: This seems like a bad method!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to seach the model on the client.

```
function buildConstraintGrid(taskId) {

    //find the right TaskId
    var taskData = jQuery.grep(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Tasks)), function(obj) {
        return obj.TaskId === taskId;
    });

    var grid = jQuery("#MyGrid");

    grid.jqGrid({
        data: taskData[0].TaskConstraints, 
        datatype: 'local',
```